# how to plot a large graph in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have a large igraph (476.8 Mb), but i can't plot it. it takes a long time (over hour) and still running. do you have a solution?!

```
graph <- graph.adjacency(weights, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
jpeg("Graph_Plot_1.jpg")
plot.igraph(graph)
plot(graph, edge.label=round(E(graph)$weight, 3))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Why 2 `plot` instructions? Remove the first, if you want the edge labels there's no point in plotting it and to remove that code line will reduce the running time.

Comment: You tell us "(476.8 Mb)" but that is not very informative. How many nodes and edges are in your graph?

Comment: @G5W 37000 nodes and 900 million edges

Comment: @Rui same problem ... takes a long time

Comment: You want to plot such a large graph? I doubt you will be able to see anything. Isn't it better to have the graph to analyze and display subgraphs only?